# HTML CSS: How to push fixed element up when mobile keyboard shows?

Tags: android, html, css, ios

I want to push the bottom toolbar when a mobile keyboard (from the chrome app) is shown.

Please see these images:

[image: image1]

There is a toolbar for the content editable element.

[image]

When the keyboard is shown, the toolbar does not get pushed above the keyboard.

I use this style:

```
.toolbar {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem 0 2rem 0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Try to set the wrapper of the toolbar to a fixed height of 100 vh (or 100 %, but keep in mind to also apply 100 % on the html and body tag).

Answer (score 0):

Set `100vh` as height in your code of your `body` tag...

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it does not work

Comment: @AlvinStefanus Can you share your `full code` with us or a `illustration` one would also be enough, please.

Comment: go to https://note.digilifesoftware.com

Comment: is there any testing username and password? to get into and check?